# javascript - how to understand if two different spans are in the same line?

Tags: javascript

I've got a div styled with CSS's `wrap` property. It has a fixed width and when content exceeds the maximum allowed it breaks into different lines. I'm building up an application where I need to understand whether different span elements are in the same line or not. Let me give an example:

```
<div style="width: 300px;" class="wrap">
    <span style="font-size:15px;color:red;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</span>
    <span style="font-size:17px;color:green;"> Vivamus in mauris dui, non posuere</span>
</div>
```

A live example as well: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3LW9/1/)

I need to understand 3 cases:

- When the span starts in the same line but ends in a different line.
- When the span starts in a different line but ends in the same line.
- When the spans start and end in the same line.

**What I've done till now:**

- If the spans have the same font-size it is easy to estimate with the `offsetTop` property. I tried it and it works properly.
- However, when spans have different font-sizes, they'll have different `offsetTop` as well. When the font-size is smaller, the `offsetTop` increases and the vica-versa, therefore it is hard to estimate using this property.
- Finally, equalizing the font-sizes will not work as well because when you change the font-size a span that fits to one line may have to be divided into two lines (e.g when font-size increases from 13px to 25px).

So, in short, how would you understand it using pure javascript? Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3LW9/1/) to play around.

Comment: Having to do this in the first place sounds bad...

Comment: @ThiefMaster, yeah, but unfortunately Javascript is not only fancy effects :)

Comment: @SavasVedova you could check the font sizes as well and calculate.

Comment: Why do (you  think) you need to do this?

Comment: @Eric, long story short: I'm building a WYSIWYG editor and for minor cursor bugs I need it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <span id='first'>Lorem elit</span><span id='second'> Vivamus amet, consectetur</span>
</div> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

<script>
    /* Check if span is broken into two lines or not */
    var firstBefore = document.createElement('span'),
        firstAfter = document.createElement('span'),
        secondBefore = document.createElement('span'),
        secondAfter = document.createElement('span');

    first.insertBefore(firstBefore, first.childNodes[0]);
    first.appendChild(firstAfter);
    second.insertBefore(secondBefore, second.childNodes[0]);
    second.appendChild(secondAfter);

    var firstBroken = (firstBefore.offsetTop === firstAfter.offsetTop) ? false : true,
        secondBroken = (secondBefore.offsetTop === secondAfter.offsetTop) ? false : true;

    /* Since the spans' baselines seem to be aligned by default, lets compared that instead */
    first.offsetBottom = (first.offsetTop + first.offsetHeight);
    second.offsetBottom = (second.offsetTop + second.offsetHeight);

    /* Main logic */
    if (first.offsetBottom === second.offsetBottom) {
        if (!firstBroken && !secondBroken) {
            alert('Begins and ends on the same line');
        } else if (firstBroken) {
            alert('Begins on different lines, but end on the same line');
        }
    } else {
        if (firstBroken) {
            alert('Begins and ends on different lines');
        } else {
            alert('Begins on the same line, but ends on different lines');   
        }
    }​​
</script>
```

Or play with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/RYEnY/1/

Be sure to run with different lengths of text.

It works by first inserting a hidden `<span>` at the beginning and end of each target `<span>` you want to detect. The code then checks if the target `<span>` is broken up into two lines by comparing the `offsetTop` of the hidden spans. Then, it grabs the offsets of the baseline of each target span and logically deducts whether the spans begin/end on the same lines or not.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like that (it uses query):

```
var span1 = $('#span1');
var span2 = $('#span2');
var offsetTop1 = getOffsetTop(span1);//you've to count offsetTop there
var offsetTop2 = getOffsetTop(span2);
var height1 = span1.height();
var height2 = span2.height();

if (Math.abs((offsetTop1 + height1) - (offsetTop2 + height2)) < 1) { //you can increase accuracy
    // two spans are in the same line
}
```